# PM2 request received but not proceed

Tags: node.js, debian, pm2

I'm using pm2 on a debian server to manage my node js application.
Pm2 receive request from a nginx reverse proxy.

During "high load", request seems to be sent to pm2 but not processed - my node app don't received them

Exemple of log that i can see in pm2 logs (i use morgan :method :host :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length])

POST DOMAIN PATH - - ms - -

POST DOMAIN PATH2 - - ms - -

It seems that pm2 close the connection on his own.

During those load, cpu is not at 100%, and there's plenty of ram available (8 worker using 500mb with 32go ram available).

Plenty of disk is also available, network interface is not even at 20%.

Don't know from where to investigate...

Answer (score 0):

Use `pm2 list` to check status of you application. Verify particuary the uptime column, to see if you process have restart or not.

I process has restarted, this tell you thatyou have an error in your node.js app that make the process restart. Then, check the PM2 error log for you process. It will tell you what's going wrong.